# Why OpenerView reduces the size of my equation

Tags: output-formatting

In this code the equation comes out with the right size.

```
acel = Style[
  DisplayForm[
   RowBox[{SuperscriptBox["v", 2], "=", 
     SubsuperscriptBox["v", "0", 2], "+ 2a Δx", 
     " ⟶ ", 
     FrameBox[
      "a =" FractionBox[SubsuperscriptBox["- v", "0", 2], 
        "2Δx"], Background -> LightBlue]}]], 24, Black, 
  Bold, FontFamily -> "Kalam"]
```

But this same code inside the `OpenerView` reduces the size of the equation that is inside the `Frame`. Why?

```
OpenerView[{"AAA", Style[acel, 30]}, Method -> "Active"]
```

Or Simply

```
OpenerView[{"AAA", acel}, Method -> "Active"]
```

Comment: Add `ScriptLevel->0` to your Style wrapper.